# Use ErrorBoundary together with asynchronous lifecycle-functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous

I want to build a React-component which loads the data asynchronously on `componentDidMount`.

This is what the function currently looks like (written in `TypeScript`):

```
async componentDidMount(): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const { props: { teamId }, state: { } } = this;
        const awaitableData = await UrlHelper.getDataAsync("some-fancy-url");

        // ... do something with awaitableData
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("Some error occured");
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The `render`-function returns the markup wrapped in a `ErrorBoundary` component, which has `componentDidCatch` implemented.
However, this is never called/triggered when the awaited call is rejected and I end up in the `catch`-block.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 21):

`async` function is syntactic sugar for a regular function that returns a promise. An error in `async` function results in rejected promise. Even if rejected promise isn't handled anywhere and results in `Uncaught (in promise)` error, it is not caught by error boundaries.

As [the reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) states,

> Error boundaries do not catch errors for: <...> Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame callbacks)

A solution is to change component state on error and handle it on next render.  `render` is the place where error can be re-thrown synchronously.

An [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/uBqkQpHz6voH1WJtJ4Zr?p=preview):

```
  state = { error: null };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      throw new Error('Foo error');
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error });
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      throw this.state.error;
    }

    return (
      <p>Foo</p>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using the [above or below example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50024796/6207266) with a functional component

provided a solution, something like this, for me:

```js
    const SomComponent: JSX.Element = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({error: null, info: null})

    ... // something here setState the error

        if (state.error) {
          throw new Error('example') // Example throws to the error boundary
        }
        return <div> Some Component </div>
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

lets take a look to the [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html)

basically it says:

> Error boundaries are React components that catch JavaScript errors
>   anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display
>   a fallback UI instead of the component tree that crashed. Error
>   boundaries catch errors during rendering, in lifecycle methods, and in
>   constructors of the whole tree below them.

so basically when you are trying to use the ASYNC/AWAIT and it fails it will go out for the CATCH side of your function:

```
catch(e) {
    console.log("Some error occured");
    throw e;
}
```

and the error will not be thrown by the `componentDidMount`. actually if you remove the try catch method, the `componentDidMount` will take care of the error.

Comment: Removed the `try/catch` but still the `componentDidCatch` is not getting hit. Only in dev-tools I can see `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Internal Server Error` from the part where the promise is rejected `reject(new Error(xhr.statusText))`.

Comment: @KingKerosin can you put the code inside the componentDidCatch?

Comment: Which code? And what should happen? The `componentDidCatch` is never hit