# How to trigger React error boundaries when Promises are rejected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, promise, axios

The issue I am having is that errors thrown in promises are not caught in an error boundary component.

The code fetches data from the server and uses the status code to determine what to do with the data from the response. `axios` is used as the client and an interceptor is set up to handle the responses.

```js
API.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  switch (response.status) {
    case 500:
    case 403:
      throw new Promise((resolve) => resolve(response.status));
  }
});
```

I have set up an `ErrorBoundary` component to catch errors thrown in its child components:

```js
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasError: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error) {
    this.setState({
      hasError: true,
    });

    if (error instanceof Promise) {
      error.then(() => console.log(error));
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.hasError ? (
      <span>Something went wrong but it is okay</span>
    ) : (
      this.props.children
    );
  }
}
```

It is used as:

```js
<ErrorBoundary>
  <Child />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

The `Child` component fetches some data from the server in the `componentDidMount` method.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  API.getData().then((data) => {
    ...
  });
}
```

When the server responds with a status code that causes the `Promise` to be thrown, the `ErrorBoundary` component should catch it but it doesn't. If an error is explicitly thrown inside the `componentDidMount` method, then the error boundary reacts accordingly. For example:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  throw new Error(); 
  // or throw new Promise(resolve => resolve());
}
```

The error can always be caught with `catch` but is there a way to have these errors be caught by the `ErrorBoundary` component?

Comment: The error thrown will be catched by the Api call. throw an error from the catch block of the api call, which will be catched by the error boundaries

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50024796/685895